# Couldn't clear an ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-gridview

I have a `GridView` backed by an `ArrayAdapter`. Everything works except for one thing: I couldn't clear that adapter (need this when refreshing the `GridView).

This is what I have:

```
adapter.clear();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Prior to this project I  have never had any issue regarding adapter clearing. I can't find what I am doing wrong here.

Any idea? (don't hesitate to ask for specific details).

Thanks!

Comment: have you checked the size of adapter after clear()? using something like countItems()?

Comment: My only guess is that it may be automatically recreated by something else in your code - without the code itself it's difficult to guess :)

Comment: @MocialovBoris The size doesn't change!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved.

I had to keep a reference on the collection that the adapter was taking its data from and then do:

```
myCollection.clean();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I was originally doing this, but thought, since the Adapter had a clear function anyway, It would be best to use that.. What is the point of it if we cannot??